# slick.js навигация

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, click

Пытаюсь сделать навигацию по слайдам.
Имеются пункты меню:
Слайд1, слайд 2, слайд3, Слайд 4

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии например на "слайд 4" происходила прокрутка к 4 слайду?

В интернете нашел подобное, но инфа старая и у меня не работает.

Comment: добавьте хотя бы сниппет с проблемой. У слика есть методы ручного перелистывания, в чем проблема с их использованием?

Comment: $('.slide1').slick('slickGoTo',4) сделал так, но перехода нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `slickGoTo`. индексация слайдов с 0.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#slider").slick({
     arrows: false,
  });
  
  $(".x").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#slider").slick("slickGoTo", $(this).data('to'));
  });
});
```

```css
#slider > div {
   
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 4rem;
   font-weight:bold;
   padding: 2rem;
   margin: 2rem;
   background: #f0f0f0;
   border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
   color: #707070;
}

.x {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="x" data-to="0">1</a>
<a href="#" class="x" data-to="1">2</a>
<a href="#" class="x" data-to="2">3</a>

<div id="slider">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо